# Difference between rel error and xerror in rpart regression trees

Tags: cart, rpart

Wondering what the difference is between rel error (relative error) and xerror (apparent error) in regression trees?

I am using the rpart package and the output returns these metrics cross-validated over the number of splits.

Anyone know the difference between these two quantities or perhaps even the formulas?

Answer (score 4):

The "rel error" is $1 - R^2$ Root mean squared error, similar to linear regression. This is the error on the observations used to estimate the model.

The "xerror" is related to the [PRESS statistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRESS_statistic). This is the error on the observations from cross validation data.

Answer (score 3):

Can not comment but 1-r^2 is not called Root mean squared error, Root mean squared error is RMSE, The square root of MSE

r^2 is called coefficient of determination, which is SSR/SSTO

SSR = total error sum of (predicted value - mean value)^2
SSTO = total error sum of (real value - mean value)^2

can also be calculated by 1 - SSE/SSTO
SSE = total error sum of (real value - predicted value)^2

But I am not one hundred percent sure rel error is 1-r^2, since in rpart, there are two cases: regression and category, I think the definition should be different for this two cases